# Installing 403-ath_regd_optional.patch

Tags: wireless, patch, backport, ath9k

I'm new to patching and I need to install this patch https://dev.openwrt.org/browser/trunk/package/kernel/mac80211/patches/rev=39442

This is supposed to patch `backports-3.15.1-1` package

As you can see it patches three files, `drivers/net/wireless/ath/regd.c`, `drivers/net/wireless/ath/Kconfig` and `.local-symbols`

I tried `patch -Np5 -i 403-ath_regd_optional.patch` and `patch -i 403-ath_regd_optional.patch` and I get the same error

> can't find file to patch at input line 3
>
> Perhaps you should have used the -p or --strip option?
>
> The text leading up to this was:
>
> |--- a/drivers/net/wireless/ath/regd.c
>
> |+++ b/drivers/net/wireless/ath/regd.c
>
> File to patch:

However, if I entered the exact same file (i.e. `drivers/net/wireless/ath/regd.c`) it works

Why is that happening?

---

UPDATE

I manually updated the files and replaced the old ones

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for patching a package is:

```
sudo patch `which [NAME OF THE PACKAGE]` < [DIRECTORY OF THE PATCH FILE]/[PATCH FILE NAME].patch
```

Example:

```
sudo patch `which webcamstudio` < ~Downloads/diff_webcamstudio_uname.patch
```

Comment: So, in my case it should be `sudo patch 403-ath_regd_optional < 403-ath_regd_optional.patch` if I'm in the same directory?

Comment: I included it in answer. there should be `` marks. also `which` is needed.

Comment: you need to patch `backports-3.15.1-1` package. isnt it? if so, the command is defferent. package name should be `backports-3.15.1-1`

Comment: Still, same errors